# Generate dynamically a menu of links vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, hyperlink, import-from-excel

In my program I need to display the names of all opened workbooks of Excel in the Task Bar and their corresponding sheets in a form so that the user can select one workbook with one sheet to import it's data. Knowing that I have the list of full path's stored in string, still the problem is that I don't know how to generate like a menu of checkbox's that contains the path of the workbooks and sheets so that when the user selects one of the checkbox's, the full path is to be passed to the import function; any ideas; Help is very appreciated.

remark:FNAME contains the full path of excel workbooks

```
 Dim offset = 60
 Dim offset1 = 50
 Dim f As Integer = 0
 For Each cur In FName
    Dim checkBox As New System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox()
    Me.Controls.Add(checkBox)
    checkBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(offset, offset1)
    checkBox.Text = cur
    checkBox.Checked = True
    checkBox.Name = "CKB" & f
    checkBox.Size = New Size(1000, 20)
    'offset = offset + 100
    offset1 += 25
    f += 1
Next
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I tried to generate checkbox's dynamically and it well worked but the problem is that i cant pass the path of the selected checkbox because i cant use the method checkbox.CheckedChanged and also i have a problem with naming the checkbox's

Comment: Thanks - You should edit your question instead of adding code in comments

Comment: Yeah that's right programmers are always in hurry :p btw i added the code do you have any suggestion for the code above ? @SamMakin

Comment: Thanks for tidying up :) I know the feeling but sometimes haste <> speed.  Is my answer below of any use - you can use it with the CheckedChanged event.

Comment: But the problem is that the checkbox's are created onload of the form and i can't access the events like checkedchnaged while coding ! you see ? @SamMakin

Comment: Hello @GiorgiNakeuri please do you have any suggestion; I have no clue how to access the events of checkbox's after creating them dynamically thank you!

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the CheckBox's `Tag` property to the file path, then in it's events it will be visible on `Sender.Tag`.  Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) out.

To set events on the controls you should use AddHandler.  See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more info!